# Valve Hammer Editor 3.4 won't load manually created map

Tags: hammer

I'm working with **Valve Hammer Editor 3.4** and trying to create a Counter-Strike 1.6 map with it. For this purpose, I've followed a YouTube tutorial.

I'm facing a problem where the editor won't run any map I created, it just says that map couldn't be loaded.

My log file is here:
https://pastebin.com/QQHPXJGY

Comment: Hi CoNe! Unfortunately, that log doesn't give us much information to work with. Can you tell us a bit about the maps you've tried opening, or where you got them from? Troubleshooting particular gamedev tools usually goes better using the support channels offered by the tool's creators, if that's an option.

Comment: The fact is whenever i try to creat cs 1.6 map in valve hammer editor 3.4  thing it is,when i finish it and try to run it in their program it finish like this.I was watching tutorials on you tube how to configure hamer editor and i made it same,but for them it did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple days of looking for solution of problem i found the right one.All what you need to do is to download new compiler what is not going with valve,perhaps i use Batch Compiler.You can find on youtube or google how to set it up and you are ready to go.